# How do I get notes to show up on my posts?

Tags: tumblr

I've been using this theme that I love very much:

Preview: *http://yuki-th.tumblr.com/*
Codes: *http://pastebin.com/HPf2EkHD*

And it does not have the option to show notes. I was wondering if I can have my notes show beneath the posted and reblog line?